# Double GOTO Command - DOS-Based Clock

Tags: batch-file, goto

I'm making a DOS-Based clock with blinking black/white background every seconds but goto command can't use like the code below the first goto makes the command runs only in the :CLOCK label
can anyone help me about this?

```
@echo off 
title DOS-Based Clock 
color a 
cls
goto CLOCK
goto 0a
:CLOCK
cls
echo The current time is: %time%
goto CLOCK
:0a
color 0a
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1>nul
goto 7a
:7a
color 7a
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1>nul
goto 0a
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40164/should-we-close-fix-my-program-questions

Comment: do I need to delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off 
    title DOS-Based Clock 
    set "color=0a"

:clock
    cls
    color %color%
    echo the current time is: %time%

    ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 > nul
    goto %color%

:0a
    set "color=7a"
    goto clock

:7a
    set "color=0a"
    goto clock
```

Use a variable to store the color and use it both to change the color and to jump to the same label as the color, then change the value of the color and repeat the process